# НДС-налог взимается(,) исходя из доходов

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> НДС-налог взимается(,) исходя из доходов, которые фирма получает.

А здесь?

> Кот прятался(,) изходя из того, шёл ли человек близко, или он шёл далеко.

Comment: Тема интересная, почему поставлен минус?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***НДС-налог взимается исходя из доходов, которые фирма получает*** — не обособляется; *взимается исходя из доходов* — сказуемое.

***Кот прятался исходя из того, шёл ли человек близко, или он шёл далеко*** — то же самое; *прятался исходя из того* — сказуемое.

Везде входит в состав сказуемого; не обособляем.

---

Чаще всего оборот с предлогом *исходя из* обособляется, если в нем указывается источник:

*Исходя из вышесказанного, можно сделать вывод, что данный метод не является эффективным*;

*Исходя из этих данных, можно предположить, что спрос на товар будет расти*;

*Исходя из того, что вы говорите, можно сделать вывод, что вы не понимаете ситуацию*.

В остальных случаях он чаще всего **входит в состав сказуемого**.

Comment: Максим, оборот не входит в сказуемое, Существует тесная связь обстоятельства со сказуемым. А если входит, то кокой состав у такого сказуемого? Это СИС или СГС? Или что это?

Comment: @Sharon А если тесно связан, а не входит, то всë равно не обособляется?

Comment: Кот – производитель действия, там скорее обособляется.  Здесь ссылка нужна: Розенталь, примечание к п. 4  Деепричастные конструкции http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113